# Does process linking still load o files in libc.a?

Tags: linker, centos, libc

I am looking at this [lecture note](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/111/notes/The_Visible_OS.pdf) (slide #6):

1. file.o contains external symbols and defined symbols
2. libc.a contains .o files for all library functions.
3. Process of linking: scan libc.a for symbols declared external by file.o, load appropriate .o files.

`ar -t /usr/lib/libc.a # lists all the .o files in libc.a`

But on my CentOS 7 host I don't see anything.

```
$ ar -t /usr/lib/libc.a
ar: /usr/lib/libc.a: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But on my CentOS 7 host I don't see anything.

Look for `/usr/lib64/libc.a`. Also learn how to look for files: studying `man find` and `man locate` would likely help you in the future.

That said, your notes paint a significantly incorrect picture.

First, most modern compilers have integrated preprocessor. The `cccp` / `gcc -E` stage is not usually performed as a separate stage. Rather, the preprocessor is run as part of the normal compilation, and its output is immediately consumed by the `gcc -c` stage.

Second, most modern Unix / Linux systems use shared libraries, which means that `libc.a` is never linked, and `libc.so.6` is used to resolve the symbols instead. (For this reason, `libc.a` may not even be installed on your system.)

Indeed your notes mention `ld.so` and `libc.so`, so the lecturer expected dynamic linking to be used. It's unclear why he / she mentioned `libc.a` at all, since it's not used in the dynamic linking case.

This:

> ld.so is the dynamic linker: turns an a.out into a process.

is also incorrect: the process *exists* before `ld.so` starts running.

The section about `printf` getting statically linked into executables `file1` and `file2`, which then both link to `__vsprintf` from `libc.so` may have been correct at some distant past, but is not correct on any moderately recent Linux system.

There are probably more misleading "facts" further on. TL;DR: these notes are wrong on too many details to be actually useful.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.